# How make dynamic php page for all queries in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to retrieve dynamic query PHP pages. First page passing values of city or id  next page by post method.

I know here sql injection can done.
but i m using in it on private network and every user session is tracked.
and table1 is protected.

Table looks like this:

**TABLE1**

```
-----------------------------------------------------
1     select * from tablename1 where ID = $id
2     select * from tablename1 where city = $city
2     select * from tablename1 where ID = $id  and city = $city
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Now I run page contain code:

```
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $city= $_POST["city"];
    $tabledata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 ");
    $a=mysql_fetch_row($tabledata );

    $query_table=$a['1']; // retrieve sql query from table1 which stored in 2nd column
    echo " $query_table"; // display query
    $result = mysql_query($query_table);

    while ($field = mysql_fetch_row( $result) )
    {
        echo "<td> $field[1] </td>";
    }
```

Now, the problem is that I can't get results. `$result` is empty?

How pass `$city` or `$id` value to query?

But if I remove `WHERE`condition from **TABKE1** then it works well. So, how can I make for `WHERE` condition to pass parameters?

how can i do this . any other option here to call stored query on 1 table and process it on other page and oher table

Comment: Before you go any further, obligatory suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query in table1 should be like this

```
-----------------------------------------------------
1     select * from tablename1 where ID = '".$id."'
2     select * from tablename1 where city = '".$city."'
3     select * from tablename1 where ID =  '".$id."'  and city =  '".$city."'
-----------------------------------------------------
```

and proceed further with your coding and it will show you the result.

OPTION 2:

Table 1:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
1     select * from tablename1 where ID =  
2     select * from tablename1 where city =  
-----------------------------------------------------
```

and change in php code like this

```
$query_table=$a['1']." '".$id."'" ;
```

or

```
$query_table=$a['2']." '".$city."'" ;
```

OPTION 3:

Table 1:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
1     select * from tablename1  

-----------------------------------------------------
```

and change in php code like this

```
$query_table=$a['1']." where ID = '".$id."'" ;
```

or

```
$query_table=$a['1']." where ID = '".$id."' AND city = '".$city."' " ;
```

Comment: not working ... display as 
select * from tablename1 where ID = '".$id."'  not value of $id

Comment: its work but for " select * from tablename1 where ID =  And City = " is not working . give me solution for this.

Comment: check my edited answer, you can't give query like this `select * from tablename1 where ID = And City = `

Comment: give answer for option 2. table 1 consist various join queries,complected queries etc. Option 3 is not suitable because i want to change php code every time

Comment: In that case You have to use option 1,because there is no other way to pass values to params query.

Comment: thanks for  answer.  any other way to do this. like PDO or Procedure etc.

Comment: I dont have ideas in PDO or procedures. If you post in question that you want PDO, some others who have knowledge in it Might help

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result with ID or City

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID = '$id' OR city = '$city'");
```

and If you want with both mandatory

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID = '$id' AND city = '$city'");
```

Comment: read quetion carefully.  TABLE1 only contains queries. and used for another tables